# Application page reloads on auto token refresh in private browsing, with okta-react sdk

Tags: reactjs, okta

I am using `@okta/okta-react v4.1.0` and `@okta/okta-auth-js v4.5.1` in my ReactJS application.

My `OktaAuth` instance looks like this:

```
    new OktaAuth({
    issuer: "issuer",
    clientId: "clientId",
    pkce: false,
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/implicit/callback",
    tokenManager: {
             autoRenew: true,
             expireEarlySeconds: 5 * 60 // expire 5 mins early 
           }   
    });
```

It is expected that 5 mins before expiry of `access` token, the `okta-react SDK`should make a GET call to `/authorize?clientId=` endpoint and fetch a new valid access token and should replace that in browser's application storage.

This transition appear smooth when I am **not** using a private browsing session (Incognito Mode).

But, when I am accessing this application in a private browsing session, while renewing this token ,my application page reloads and hence clears out any unsaved data available on the screen.

The different thing I noticed in private browser session *network* tab, is that,

- 3 calls were made to `/authroize?clientId=` endpoint, while in `normal` browser session, it was just 1.
- the 3 api calls have their Status Codes as `200`, `302`, `200`, while in `normal` session it was just `200`.

It appears the second API `Get`call, is forcing a redirect to `redirectUrl` and hence a page load, but why only in case of *private session*.

Answer (score 2):

As you have observed, browsers started blocking third party cookies, so browser doesn't recognise that there is already an Okta session.

If you are using a SPA app, you can start using refresh token with rotation: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/refresh-tokens/refresh-token-rotation/

Thank you,
Raj

Comment: Were you able to get refresh token in s SPA app that was using auth code flow?

Answer (score 0):

After some discussions , When I allow the third party cookies in my incognito browser session, this behavior cease to exist.  So yes, for timebeing, using this as a solution.

Comment: Did you found permanent solution? We are also facing this issue when keeping the tab idle for long time (which is around token expiry time), page gets auto reload and whatever unsaved changes are there they are rollback to it's original state.

Let me know if you were able to find permanent solution.

Comment: @SunilGulabani, no permanent solution. But you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/65840136/7306148  solution as Pruthvi shared above.